# R - Lines() in a for loop

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to add a line to each one of the plots that I generate with a for loop.
I am using this code, which creates the plot but without the red line I want to plot.

I would prefer not to use ggplot2.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

```
for (i in 3:23){
  fit <- auto.arima(ts[,i])
  frc <- forecast(fit, h=nrow(test_data))  #11 data points in the test set
  plot(frc)
  test <- c(rep(NA, times = nrow(train_data)), test_data$Var1)
  lines(ts(test, frequency = 365.25/7), col = "red")
}
```

Comment: Move `plot` outside of (before) the `for` loop.

Comment: (I also recommend against renaming a variable `forecast`, as it's confusing to me (if not R) which is which.)

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work. I need the for loop to generate all the plots. I also tried to add another for loop within the other one but also no luck.

Comment: It would help if you had a reproducible example. It might help if you use a known dataset, but perhaps a large-enough (but not huge) sample will suffice.

Comment: I managed to fix it. The problem was that the test variable was stored as a list instead of as a vector. Thanks for your help @r2evans

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

```
#Plot Prediction against Real Value
for (i in 3:23){
  fit <- auto.arima(ts[,i])
  frc <- forecast(fit, h=nrow(test_data))  #11 data points in the test set
  plot(frc)
  vf <- c(test_data[,i])
  test <- c(rep(NA, times = nrow(train_data)), vf)
  test <- unlist(test)
  lines(test, col = "red")
}
```